# React input minLength onKeyDown

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is it possible to validate `input` `minLength` without submitting the form with `onKeyDown`? I tried to do it, but it ignores `minLength`. Because I have simple input field which doesn't require form. Here is my input field:

```
<input
      type="text"
      name="search"
      placeholder="Search events, sports, leagues"
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
      onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
    />

  const onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setSearchText(e?.target?.value)

  const handleKeyDown = async (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      history.push(EVENTS_SEARCH_BASE_PATH)
      await dispatch(searchEvents(searchQuery))
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't have an option.

My implementation at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-lumiere-147uj?file=/src/App.tsx:0-718)

Comment: Hello, I think so, I couldn't find a way and I think I will need to add a form.

Comment: If you have only one field, then you don't need to add a form.

Comment: In that case, how can we error the message? as it would be with min length and forms

Comment: I am thinking about adding react-final-form

Answer (score 1):

assuming you want the text to be more than 10 characters

in your `handleKeyDown` function try this:

```
<input
  .... 
  ...
  value={value}
  .... 
  onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
/>

const minLength = 10; 
const handleKeyDown = async (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
if (event.key === "Enter") {
  if (value.length > minLength) {
    console.log("the text length is:", value.length);
    // do stuff here
    // history.push(EVENTS_SEARCH_BASE_PATH)
    // await dispatch(searchEvents(searchQuery))
  } else {
    console.log("the text is less that " + minLength +" charachters!!!");
    // show Error message
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. If possible I wanted effect like when you have as in submit the form.